# Can't Get GCM Notification from background ios sdk

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I can't get GCM notification from background, Although can receive it on foreground such as these:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = fffff;
            title = "\U067e\U06cc\U0627\U0645";
        };
        badge = 9;
        sound = default;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1448218309944532%075c2cd9075c2cd9";
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

To get notifications in background, as per apple documentation

1. "Remote notifications" option needs to be enabled in Background modes under Capabilities in the target settings.

and normally when you receive any notification at that time **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** this method called.

and if you want to call this method in background, then you should sent a silent pushnotification. and for that you have to add **content-available** key with value **1** into the **notification payload.**

you JSON response contain that key like below example

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}
```